# Referencing closed workbook with variable part of name (or loading only one in folder)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to reference a closed workbook, which part of the name I don't know, since it changes daily. Let's say that's workbook name is "RandomName-15515", and the "15515" is changing daily to a random value.

What I tried instead, as couldn't make the above work, I set that file to be saved in a separate folder daily, so I could reference it in a way to open the only workbook in a specific directory, but when I did `filePathFX = Dir("\directory\" & Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Date), "YYYYMMDD") & "\" & "*.csv")`, it indeed finds that file but pops an error:

"Run-time error '1004': 'RandomName-15515.CSV" could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct."

Not sure how it could not be found, since it puts the actual name of the file in the error. Any ideas?

Comment: in which directory your csv files in?

Comment: I've got some confidential data in the directory I'd prefer not to share, but basically it looks like that:
\\imports\preproc\archive\aaa\xxx\yyy\zz_z\20170920 (moving date, obviously)

Comment: thats local directory or server?

Comment: That's a server.

Comment: did you mapped that directory to you local?

Comment: I didn't map it to any letter before. Now I did, and when I try to work with "Z:\preproc\archive\aaa\xxx\yyy\zz_z\20170920", same thing occurs. Please keep in mind that the error is showing the name of the file perfectly, while "not being able" to find it.

Comment: please try with this `filePathFX = Dir("Z:\preproc\archive\aaa\xxx\yyy\zz_z\" & Format(Now() - 1, "YYYYMMDD") & "\" & "RandomName-*.csv")`

Comment: Still same error. When I'm putting a name that's slightly different though, it obviously doesn't even put that filename in the error. Doesn't find anything. 
Anyways, huge thanks for your time! If you've got any different ideas I'm eager to hear them out :)

Comment: when you get the error message, while try to open that workbook?. if yes, try with full path to open the workbook

Comment: Oh my, I had an issue with the code on the other line. Missclicked an additional letter and that's why it didn't work. That's why I should post the entire code, instead of just a random single line. Thanks! Is there any way to reward you for your time if you've been putting answers in comments all the time?

Comment: Good to hear that your code is working